# how can i add card from "pending" tab to "approved" ? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

i have problem with adding my element(card) from one tab to another...

[image]

this is my code
i am using vue-cli!

```
    <el-tabs style="margin-top: 20px" v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
        <el-tab-pane label="PENDING" name="first">

            <el-row style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <el-col type="flex" :span="6" v-for="(o, index) in medias" :key="index">
                    <el-card style="margin: 5px;" class="box-card">
                        <div slot="header">
                            <h2>{{ o.author_username }}</h2>
                            <a :href="o.link">instagram</a>
                        </div>
                        <img :src="o.pic" class="image" width="430">
                        <div style="padding: 14px;">
                            <el-row :gutter="20" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <el-col :span="12">
                                    <div class="grid-content">
                                        <p>
                                            LIKES
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="text-bold-big small-margin">
                                            {{o.likes_number}}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </el-col>
                                <el-col :span="12">
                                    <div class="grid-content">
                                        <p>
                                            COMMENTS
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="text-bold-big small-margin">
                                            {{ o.comments_number }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </el-col>
                            </el-row>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="bottom clearfix">
                                <el-button type="text" @click="addRejected(o.index)" class="hide-reject-button">REJECT</el-button>
                                <el-button type="text" class="show-button">APPROVE</el-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </el-card>
                </el-col>
            </el-row>

        </el-tab-pane>
        <el-tab-pane label="APPROVED" name="second">

        </el-tab-pane>
        <el-tab-pane v-bind="rejected" label="REJECTED" name="third">

        </el-tab-pane>
    </el-tabs>
```

here is the script

```
<script>
    import mock_det from './details_mock.json'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                rejected:[],
                approved:[],
                medias: mock_det.medias,
                activeName: 'first'
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addRejected(index){
                console.log("works");
                this.rejected.push(index)
            },
            handleClick(tab, event) {
                console.log(tab, event);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

so!
i decide to simply create massive named approved and push my element there.
but i don'tn understand if i did it correctly...
'mock_det' is my json file with data for cards.
addRejected is a method by which i am pushing my data to rejected[].
help me please to solve that problem!
thank you!)

Comment: Looks like you started correctly, just don't forget to remove card from medias array

Comment: well, when i add some elements to rejected, and open rejected tab... i see nothing, it doesn't work..

Comment: This simple mechanism should work. In your example you are pushing index to the array, but reading objects, did you forget to add objects instead of index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `addRejected` click handler.
Change the button to:

```
<el-button type="text" @click="addRejected(o)" class="hide-reject-button">REJECT</el-button>
```

Also if you want the element to be removed from the `medias` array, add:

```
this.medias.splice(this.medias.find((media) => media === index), 1);
```

to the `addRejected` method

**EDIT:**

If you want the element to be visible in the rejected tab, you should remove the 
`v-bind="rejected"` from the `<el-tab-pane>` and add a `v-for` for `rejected`.

Example:

```
<el-tab-pane label="REJECTED" name="third">
    <el-row style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <el-col type="flex" :span="6" v-for="(o, index) in rejected" :key="index">
        /* Code here you want to have executed for every 'o' in 'rejected' */
        </el-col>
    </el-tab-pane>
</el-tab-pane>
```

Comment: doesn't work still..maybe i didn't explain correctly

Comment: i want to see added element inside Rejected tab!

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya I have updated my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to push o.index which might not even be defined here.

```
<el-button type="text" @click="addRejected(o.index)" class="hide-reject-button">REJECT</el-button>
```

If you want to push the object from medias you need to push o.

```
<el-button type="text" @click="addRejected(o)" class="hide-reject-button">REJECT</el-button>
```